# Combining with Union Tables in SQL (values populating incorrectly)

Tags: sql, datatables, union

I am trying to perform a Union on 2 tables in SQL, both with columns are MultiNational, CompanyDescrpition, GDPRojectID, Company_Code, 2019TTV, 2020TTV and 2021TTV. These two tables populate values into 2019TTV, 2020TTV and 2021TTV when I make the two separate tables, however when I perform the union, it turns into 3 columns all called TTV and then it just fills with the year number instead of the value that should be there.
[image: This is before the union]

[image: This is after the union]

Any idea why this is happening?

Here is how I am performing the union.

`select multinational, companydescription, GDProjectID, company_code, 2021TTV, 2020TTV, 2019TTV FROM #TTV Union select multinational, companydescription, GDProjectID, company_code, 2021TTV, 2020TTV, 2019TTV FROM #TTVUK`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have column names starting with numbers, you should contain them in square brackets like [2021TTV].

EDIT:  To clarify, if column names start with anything besides letters, you should contain the column name in square brackets or quotes.